Define Azure Pipeline For Multi-Repos
I have a project in Azure that has many repositories. All of the repositories need to run with the same pipeline, so I'm looking for a way to define the repository name as a variable.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'xxxx'

variables:
  repoName: 'repoA'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repo
      type: git
      name: '50aa1c1f-21f0-4c61-8d85-d83218e705c9/$(repoName)'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: repo

- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work?


I have a project in Azure that has many repositories. All of the repositories need to run with the same pipeline, so I'm looking for a way to define the repository name as a variable.

It's not supported to use variable as the repository name in Yaml resource. Please check the doc below:

If you would like to checkout multiple repo, and define reponame in variable, as an alternative, you can use checkout task.
- checkout: git://projectname/${{ variables.repoName}}@${{ variables.branchRef }}

It's mentioned in doc:

Please check similar ticket for the details.
Edit:

In my case there are dozens of repos, we won't be able to define and mange a pipeline for each repository.

You can use parameter to define the reponame and use each loop for checkout task.
parameters:
  - name: repoNames
    type: object
    default:
      - repo1
      - repo2
      - repo3

steps:
- checkout: self

- ${{ each repo in parameters.repoNames }}:
  - checkout: git://myproject/${{repo}}

It checks out all repos:

If you have different project name used with different repo name, you can use nested in parameters, my sample here.

Just to be more accurate, we do not have to run all the repos at the same time. It is more like when a repo has to be published, it uses the same pipeline. Actually, I used your idea to write the checkout like this: checkout: git://myproject/${{repo}}, and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

I'd like to suggest a different approach:

Create a base pipeline in a shared repository with all the stages/jobs/steps used by all repositories/applications
for each repository or application, create a pipeline that uses the base pipeline (via extends
templates).

The base pipeline will ensure a standard structure for your pipelines, and will prevent code duplication.
Yes, there will be multiple pipelines to manage. But on the other hand, you don't need to have complicated logic to determine which repository/application is being used, etc. Also, it will be much easier to customize agent pools, resources, triggers, CRON schedules for each one, if required.
Example
Base pipeline (shared templates repository):
# Project: my-project
# Repository: shared-pipeline-templates
# 
# /pipelines/base-pipeline.yaml

parameters:
  # other parameters here

  - name: applicationName
    displayName: Name of the application to build and deploy
    type: string

  # As an alternative, and in case the stages are always the same for all services,
  # consider removing this parameter and hard-code the stages in the pipeline.
  - name: environments
    displayName: List of environments to deploy to
    type: object
    default: 
      - name: dev
        dependsOn: build
      - name: qa
        dependsOn: dev
      - name: prod
        dependsOn: qa

variables:
  # Common variables that are used by all repositories/applications
  - template: /pipelines/variables/common-variables.yaml

# add common resources (used by all repositories/applications) here

stages:
  - stage: Build
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        steps:
          - script: echo Building the application
            displayName: 'Build the application'

  - ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
    - stage: ${{ environment.name }}
      displayName: Deploy ${{ environment.name }}
      dependsOn: ${{ environment.dependsOn }}
      jobs:
        - deployment: Deploy${{ environment.name }}
          displayName: Build and Deploy to ${{ environment.name }}
          environment: ${{ environment.name }} # Azure DevOps environment. Use one per environment or application/environment
          variables:
            # Get the variables for the specific application and environment
            # - template: /pipelines/variables/${{ parameters.applicationName }}/${{ environment.name }}-variables.yaml
          strategy:
            runOnce:
              deploy:
                steps:
                  - script: echo Deploying to ${{ environment.name }} Environment
                    displayName: 'Deploy to ${{ environment.name }}'

Pipeline for repository/application foo:
# /pipelines/foo-pipeline.yaml

name: foo_$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

# Add specific triggers, resources, cron schedules, etc for foo application here

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: shared
      type: git
      name: my-project/shared-pipeline-templates
      ref: releases/0.1.2

extends:
  template: /pipelines/base-pipeline.yaml@shared
  parameters:
    applicationName: foo # <----------- application name can be hard-coded or use the value of a parameter
    # other parameters here

Pipeline for repository/application bar:
# /pipelines/bar-pipeline.yaml

name: bar_$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

# Add specific triggers, resources, cron schedules, etc for bar application here

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: shared
      type: git
      name: my-project/shared-pipeline-templates
      ref: releases/0.1.2

extends:
  template: /pipelines/base-pipeline.yaml@shared
  parameters:
    applicationName: bar # <----------- application name can be hard-coded or use the value of a parameter
    # other parameters here


Thanks for your response. In my case there are dozens of repos, we won't be able to define and mange a pipeline for each repository.

@SaraHalili, if you have dozens of repos to checkout, you can use each loop with parameter for repo name, i have updated the reply with detail below, please check, thanks.
